# MSVC 19.37 doesn't consistently warn on assignment in if statements

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, compiler-warnings, diagnostics

A colleague prefers *Yoda Conditionals*:

> ```cpp
> if (0 == x) // as a safer alternative to (x == 0), to prevent the typo (x = 0)
> ```

This is a controversial style in the team, and one argument brought up against it is that compilers can consistently emit warnings to detect the buggy pattern `if (x = 0)`.

However, MSVC doesn't appear to detect this pattern for classes (https://godbolt.org/z/qqo9ee5n5):

```cpp
struct wrapper {
    int x;
    operator int();
};

void foo(wrapper w, int x) {
    if (w = wrapper{}) {} // OK ?!
    if (x = 0) {} // warning C4706: assignment within conditional expression
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a known bug? I have enabled `/Wall`, but maybe there is some other flag I am missing. IntelliSense also doesn't detect this.

If there is no way to detect this with MSVC and IntelliSense, how can I flag this automatically?

---

*Note: I am aware that if this was compiled in a CI with multiple compilers, one of them ought to catch it. However, the goal is to detect this issue locally (ideally with a linter).*

---

*Update: it's becoming clear that I haven't simply missed some flag, so I have submitted a [bug report in the Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/No-warning-for-assignment-in-if-statemen/10462364).*

Comment: Looks like an issue, to me. Even running the in-built static code analysis doesn't give a warning on the `w` assignment. Although, for that line, Yoda won't help: using `if (wrapper{} = w) {}` also generates no warning.

Comment: One idiosyncratic alternative I've seen is void return for assignment, `void operator=(wrapper const& from) { x = from.x; }`, on the basis it prevents this very problem, and doing idiomatic `return *this;` for chaining is—arguably—a bad thing.  Better than yoda conditionals, imo.

Comment: @Eljay you can't explicitly default an assignment operator which returns `void` (and it's not the default implementation in the first place), so this seems unattractive. It does catch the bug, but with some cost. Would you actually do this for simple `struct`s that otherwise wouldn't have needed any assignment operator definition?

Comment: I've been on a project where this (idiosyncratic) idiom was used extensively in C++, in the mid-1990s.  It worked out okay.  I haven't used this idiom since.  But if the alternative was yoda conditionals, I'd use it.

Comment: The clang-cl compiler that you can (optionally) install in Visual Studio flags it: *warning : using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]* Perhaps not really an ideal solution, but I have my major projects set up with a "use clang-cl" configuration that I run from time to time, just to get other/extra warnings like this.

Comment: I often do `if (auto * p = GetObject())` and I absolutely don't want to have a warning here.

Comment: @Osyotr that would be a declaration inside an if statement, which is perfectly fine. It wouldn't be fine if you wrote `if (p = GetObject())` because it's likely a typo and it was meant to be `if (p == GetObject())`. Compilers should warn you unless you parenthesize it like `if ((p = GetObject())` to express intent. The problem is that MSVC fails to warn in some cases.